# Conditionally hide and show Widget

Tags: flutter, show-hide

I am completely new to flutter started learning some time ago. I want to conditionally hide and show the following widget (**SdCardHeadlineLeft**) based on a condition which is paymentType = cash and order type = delivery based on these two conditions I want to hide it and if the condition is paymentType = isApiCheckout I want to show this widget.

I tried the Visibility widget but the problem with that is it completely hides the widget, but I want to do it on the condition

Hide:
paymentType = cash,
orderType = delivery

Show:
paymentType = isApiCheckout

```
class _TippingComponentState extends State<TippingComponent> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SdCardHeadlineLeft(
    cardHeadline: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.labelWouldYouLikeToTip,
    isExpandable: true,
    extraLineBeforeExpanded: false,
    hasButtonRight: false,
    headlineLeftBodyCard: 
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Observer(
        builder: (_) => Column(
          children: [
            _CashOrBillWidget(
              pickedCashOrBill: widget.pickedCashOrBill,
              onTipChanged: widget.onTipChanged,
            ),
            SdDividerNoPadding(positionTop: 1.0),
            if (widget.pickedCashOrBill == CashOrBill.tipOnBill)
              const TippingAmountComponent(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
    );
  }
 }
```

Comment: What issue you are getting

Comment: if I am using the Visibility widget on SdCardHeadlineLeft and set the visibility to false it completely hides it. but I don't want to use any widget to hide/show. i don't know how to do it with some conditions. without using any widget like visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a simple condition check and return a sizedbox.shrink if its not met

```dart
return paymentType == isApiCheckout?SdCardHeadlineLeft(
    cardHeadline: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.labelWouldYouLikeToTip,
    isExpandable: true,
    extraLineBeforeExpanded: false,
    hasButtonRight: false,
    headlineLeftBodyCard: 
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Observer(
        builder: (_) => Column(
          children: [
            _CashOrBillWidget(
              pickedCashOrBill: widget.pickedCashOrBill,
              onTipChanged: widget.onTipChanged,
            ),
            SdDividerNoPadding(positionTop: 1.0),
            if (widget.pickedCashOrBill == CashOrBill.tipOnBill)
              const TippingAmountComponent(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
    ): Sizedbox.shrink();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a widget called "Visibility" which can be used in the following manner:

```
Visibility(
  visible:paymentType == isApiCheckout,
  child:SdCardHeadlineLeft(...),
  replacement:SizedBox(), 
);
```

So basically it takes in a bool and if it's true, it will return 'child', if false, the 'replacement' will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

try

```dart
return  paymentType == cash &&  type = deliver? SdCardHeadlineLeft(...) : Text("you can have others widget");
```

Or

```dart
 if(paymentType == isApiCheckout) 
   return SdCardHeadlineLeft(...);

 else return  SizedBox();
```